# 64-bit version of GCC not compiling 64-bit exe

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am beginner regarding **gcc command line** compilation.
I need a help regarding **-m64** flag.

I installed gcc compiler using MinGW.
I checked for gcc version by following,
`gcc -v` command, which shows `Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32`.
So I assume, 64-bit version of gcc is installed.

**Objective**: I wrote a small program to check, if the main.exe is generated for 32 or 64 bit.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("The Size is: %lu\n", sizeof(long));
    
    return 0;   
}
```

I compiled using following command, `gcc -o main main.c`. When I execute the main.exe, it outputs, `The Size is: 4`.

But I expected the output to be `The Size is: 8'.

So i modified the command as `gcc -m64 -o main main.c`. When I executed the main.exe again, still it outputs `The Size is: 4'

How to compile for 64-bit version exe?

Comment: `printf("The Size is: %lu\n", sizeof(long));` -> `printf("The Size is: %zu\n", sizeof(void*));`

Comment: A `long` is guaranteed to be *at least* 32 bits. If you want to know whether the binary you compiled is 64 bit or not, check the size of a pointer, since that's the whole reason for N-bit being a thing. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types

Comment: On Windows, `long` is always 32bit, you should probably try `sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: Both windows and linux have ways to check if an executable is 32 or 64 bit. Use that method instead, looking at sizes of types is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Jabberwocky,sweenish, ssbssa. Thanks now it is clear. Program ran successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said in the comments, the size of `long` can be 8 or 4 bytes on a 64bit system. You can try `sizeof(size_t)` or `sizeof(void*)`. Even this might not be reliable on every system (but should work for Windows, Linux, macOS).

Comment: Yeah as you siad it will probably work but there is no guarantee. It's better to use OS functionality to tell you if an executable is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: @Fredrik In principal, I agree with you. But  you might want a portable, OS-independent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a better way of doing it.

First download **Sigcheck** from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck then run it like below:

```
C:\Sigcheck>sigcheck64.exe -u -e "C:\Sublime C++ Projects\runtime_measure.exe"

Sigcheck v2.82 - File version and signature viewer
Copyright (C) 2004-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

c:\sublime c++ projects\runtime_measure.exe:
        Verified:       Unsigned
        Link date:      7:43 PM 12/8/2021
        Publisher:      n/a
        Company:        n/a
        Description:    n/a
        Product:        n/a
        Prod version:   n/a
        File version:   n/a
        MachineType:    64-bit
```

As you can see, in this case, **runtime_measure.exe** is a 64-bit binary.

Don't forget to give the correct address so that the terminal can find and execute **sigcheck64.exe** from the directory you have placed it.

Also, notice the use of two parameters `-u` and `-e` in the command.

Answer (score 0):

x86_64-w64-mingw32:
The mingw32 is compiler that will generate 32bits executables.
The references to 64bit in you package name indicates that this compiler runs in 64bits mode.

If you wan't to generate 64 bits executables, you will need mingw64 compiler:
https://www.mingw-w64.org/

Comment: ``x86_64-w64-mingw32`` is the target name. AFAIK it is the correct target for 64bit Windows.

Comment: mingw32 means that the generated binaries are 32bit.
x86_64 means that the compiler can run on a x86_64 architecture.
w64 means that the OS is windows 96 bits.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm pretty convinced that the importance parts are "x86_64" and "w64", which indicate the hardware architecture and the os (Windows 64 bits).